# Intersection of elements of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Even I try but I can not understand the following equation:

$
Poss(A) = \bigcap_{a \in A}\lbrace e | e \in Poss(a) \rbrace
$

where $A=\lbrace a1,a2,a3 \rbrace$
and $Poss(a)$ is a set of sets, for example:

$Poss(a1)=\lbrace \lbrace 2,7 \rbrace, \lbrace 1,2,5,7 \rbrace \rbrace $

$Poss(a2)=\lbrace \lbrace 3,6 \rbrace, \lbrace 1,3,6 \rbrace \rbrace $

$Poss(a3)=\lbrace \lbrace 4,6 \rbrace, \lbrace 1,4,6 \rbrace \rbrace $

So, I am not sure which one of the following two is right? Or both are wrong?

$Poss(A)= \emptyset$ because there is no common sets between Poss(a1) Poss(a2), and Poss(a3)

OR

$Poss(A)= \lbrace 1 \rbrace$ because 1 in $\lbrace 1,2,5,7 \rbrace $ of Poss(a1), in $\lbrace 1,3,6 \rbrace $ of Poss(a2), and in $\lbrace 1,4,6 \rbrace $ of Poss(a3).

Please help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please choos your tags with care. This has *nothing* to do with `intersection-theory`.

Comment: Your first guess is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\{e\mid e\in\text{Poss}(a)\}=\text{Poss}(a)$ you might as well write: $$\text{Poss}(A)=\bigcap_{a\in A}\text{Poss}(a)$$

So actually we have:$$e\in\text{Poss}(A)\iff\forall a\in A[e\in\text{Poss}(a)]$$

So if $A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ this comes to the same as:$$e\in\text{Poss}(A)\iff [e\in\text{Poss}(a_1)\wedge e\in\text{Poss}(a_2)\wedge e\in\text{Poss}(a_2)]\tag1$$

Can you find any set $e$ that satisfies the RHS of $(1)$?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not quite good at these things. Can I ask you more.  If $Poss(a1)=\lbrace \lbrace 2,7 \rbrace, \lbrace 1,2,5,7 \rbrace \rbrace $
$Poss(a2)=\lbrace \lbrace 2,3,7 \rbrace, \lbrace 1,3,6 \rbrace \rbrace $
$Poss(a3)=\lbrace \lbrace 2,4,7 \rbrace, \lbrace 1,4,6 \rbrace \rbrace $, --> is $Poss(A)=\lbrace \lbrace 2,7 \rbrace \rbrace $ ??? This one is different from the case above, because $ \lbrace 2,7 \rbrace $ already belongs to $Poss(a1)$

Comment: No. $\{2,7\}$ is an element of $Poss(a1)$ but definitely is not an element of $Pos(a_2)$ (which has 2 elements that are both not equal to $\{2,7\}$). Again the answer is $\varnothing$ here.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question. If Poss(A) represents the intersections of each element of Poss(a1) with each element of Poss(a2) (and Poss(a3) and so on), how can I represent it by mathematical equation? I just want to make myself really understand math.

Comment: Then $\text{Poss}(A)=\{a\cap b\cap c\mid a\in\text{Poss}(a_1),b\in\text{Poss}(a_2),c\in\text{Poss}(a_3)\}$. If my answer is enough for you to understand, then you should accept it.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining.